# character encoding puzzle with PHP/MS Access

Tags: php, sql, ms-access, character-encoding

NB This is MS Access 2000, and this PHP file is called with an ajax call...

At the start of this PHP file I have put

```
ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');
```

The $token below comes from these lines

```
$search_string = $_GET[ 'search_string' ];
$search_tokens = explode( " ", $search_string );
$token = $search_tokens[ 0 ];
```

This works OK when I have a "token" without French accented characters:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM tblFrEng WHERE French = '$token'";
echo "=== SQL is $sql<br>";
$sth = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
$sth->execute();
```

But although the *SQL* with a French word like "référé" looks fine (like this):

```
=== SQL is SELECT * FROM tblFrEng WHERE French = 'référé'
```

unfortunately the query returns 0 rows... even though there are records it should return... so it seems likely to me that character encoding has got to be the problem

NB I also tried encoding using utf8_encode but this, as was pointed out, makes no sense and garbled the SQL string...

Comment: Where do you get this `$token` from?

Comment: token is taken from a GET string... I'll put those lines in

Comment: I think the encoding of your file is not UTF8...

Comment: Calling `utf8_encode()` here doesn't make sense. The function converts ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8. `$token` ought to be in UTF-8 already. If you're getting something, then perhaps the text in the database is incorrectly encoded.

Comment: @cleong thanks... this makes sense.  Any idea how I can tackle the question of incorrect dbase encoding?  Thing is I already have another program, written in Jython (i.e. Java) which manages this lookup function (on this database) without any problems... including with French accented characters.

Comment: If you have another program that depends on the incorrect encoding, then I guess you have to stick with it. `utf8_decode` ought to unscramble the output.

Comment: actually no it doesn't matter if the other program stops working... it is certainly seems likely to me (not that I know much about it) that utf8_decode should work... if ever I do get any output from the dbase... the problem is that either the PHP or the dbase is doing something funny with the text sent to it... that's really what I'm trying to get to understand

Comment: @cleong your comments have made me suspect that the PHP is the culprit here... if it works OK in Jython it seems like MS Access is able to handle the UTF-8 sent to it... thing is it seems such a basic question!

Comment: @mikerodent So when you var_dump the $_GET token you get weird characters?

Comment: It's certainly possible that it's an issue with the PDO ODBC driver. On Windows side at least, it relies on API calls that are seriously dated.

Comment: @silkfire... no, no weird characters at that point, it's about the communication between this script and MS Access

Comment: @cleong wow... OK I have 2 plan Bs, one to try mysqli, the other to convert the MS Access dbase to MySQL... this is feasible.  I'm just surprised!

Comment: Try assessing the database through an ADOBE COM object. There are sample code in the comment section in the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/class.com.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the PHP code I got working. I had to use `mb_convert_encoding()`, which is part of the PHP "Multibyte String" ("mbstring") extension.

The code:

```
<?php
// NB: save this PHP script as an ANSI text file, not a UTF-8 encoded file

$dbh = new PDO(
        'odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};' .
        'Dbq=C:\\Users\\Public\\acc2000.mdb;' .
        'Uid=Admin;Pwd=;');

// this is our test case
$city = 'Montréal';
echo '$city: ' . $city . "\r\n";

// this is the UTF-8 "token" we'd get from the AJAX call...
$token = utf8_encode($city);
echo '$token: ' . $token . "\r\n";

// ...and here we convert to the Access_2000 character set
$win_token = mb_convert_encoding($token, 'Windows-1252', 'UTF-8');
echo '$win_token: ' . $win_token . "\r\n";

$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM Cities WHERE City = ?');
$sth->Execute(array($win_token));
$rst = $sth->fetchAll();
echo '$rst: ';
print_r($rst);
```

The result when run from the Windows command line:

```
C:\__tmp>\php\php odbcTest.php
$city: MontrΘal
$token: Montr├⌐al
$win_token: MontrΘal
$rst: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [City] => MontrΘal
            [0] => MontrΘal
        )

)
```

Note that the command-line output *itself* is slightly garbled, but at least the SQL query returned a result....

Comment: you're a genius!  I find I have to do a *reverse* encoding with the returned stuff (I'm doing it within the PHP file not at the CLI)... so I go echo mb_convert_encoding( $row[ 'Def' ], 'UTF-8', 'Windows-1252');

Comment: ah, just one fly in the ointment (not that surprising)... it seems that linebreaks in Access "Memo" fields are completely ignored (I've split the incoming string up into chars)... These linebreaks have always been problematic... think I'll probably convert to MySQL in due course, but thanks very much